# Script to geth count of Memory, CPU and Swap

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, ssh

I have a below script which is working but seems too slow, I'm not expert on the shell as still in learning process hence not getting much idea to make it more smarter.

Will appreciate any ideas on this.

**MY CODE:**

```
#!/bin/bash
CurrntTime=$(date +'%m/%d/%Y %T')

read -rsp $'Please Enter password below: ' SSHPASS
export SSHPASS
echo -e  "\n"
printf "%s %-38s  %s\n" "Server_Name                         CPU  Memory  Swap"
printf '%s\n' "-------------------------------------------------------"

for server in $(cat /home/user1/mem)
do
cpu_info=$(sshpass -e ssh -q -t  $server sudo grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | awk 'NF==3{count++} END {printf count}')
mem_info=$(sshpass -e ssh -q -t $server sudo free -g | awk '/Mem:/{printf $2}')
swap_info=$(sshpass -e ssh -q -t $server sudo free -g | awk '/Swap:/{printf $2}')
printf "%s %-38s  %s\n" "$server          $cpu_info   $mem_info     $swap_info"

done | tee -a  2>/dev/null
```

**SCRIPT OUTPUT:**

```
$ ./cpu-memory-count.sh
Please Enter password below:

Server_Name                          CPU  Memory  Swap
-------------------------------------------------------
udc0150.exmapl.udc.com          8   15     2
udc0196.exmapl.udc.com          8   15     2
udc0193.exmapl.udc.com          8   15     2
udc0160.exmapl.udc.com          8   15     2
udc0146.exmapl.udc.com          1   15     2
```

**Note:** I am not saving output to any of the file rather just getting them printed on the console.

**EDIT:**

Due to some security reasons we are not able to use `ansible` and `key-baed` access hence i used `sshpass` along with ssh need to become `sudo` where it required root privileges to get the information.

Comment: `NF==3{count++}` Why NF==3? `printf "%s %-38s  %s\n" "$server          $cpu_info` Did you mix quoting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do not use `sshpass`. Instead copy private key to remote locations. see `ssh-copy-id`.
2. Do not create 3 separate connections to each server. Create **one** connection per server.
3. Connect to servers in parallel.
4. Do not allocate psuedoterminal when you do not use terminal features...
5. I see no reason to use `sudo` to get to `/proc/cpuinfo` nor to `free`. `grep` has `-c` option. And there's `nproc`.
6. Remove useless `| tee -a` from the end.
7. Do not reinvent the wheel and use a tool - research `ansible` and similar automation utilities.

That said, I could see a function, export it, then run `bash` from inside `xargs`. GNU `xargs` has `-P` option to run stuff in parallel:

```
work() {
   server=$1
   # ONE connection
   tmp=$(ssh "$server" bash -c 'nproc; free -g')
   # parsing later
   cpu_info=$(<<<"$tmp" awk 'NR==1')
   mem_info=$(<<<"$tmp" awk '/Mem:/{printf $2}')
   swap_info=$(<<<"$tmp" awk '/Swap:/{printf $2}')
   # outputting
   printf "%-40s %5s %5s %5s\n" "$server" "$cpu_info" "$mem_info" "$swap_info"
}
export -f work
< /home/user1/mem xargs -P0 -n1 -d'\n' bash -c 'work "$@"' _
```

> Could you please explain 'work "$@"' _ , as i'm still learning. if you could that will be really helpfu

`< /home/user1/mem` redirects the content of the file `/home/user1/mem` to standard input of the command. The command is `xargs`. `xargs` reads `-d'\n'` data separates with newlines (lines...) from the standard input, and passes `-n1` one argument to the command that followed. So it executes `bash -c 'work "$@"' _ <the_line>` on each line. `-P0` makes it do that concurrently.

From `man bash` we can read:

> -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after the
> command_string, **the first argument is assigned to $0** and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.  The assign‐
> ment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

and:

> @      Expands  to  the positional parameters, starting from one.  In contexts where word splitting is performed, this expands each positional pa‐
> rameter to a separate word; if not within double quotes, these words are subject to word splitting.  In contexts where  word  splitting  is
> not  performed, this expands to a single word with each positional parameter separated by a space.  When the expansion occurs within double
> quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word.  **That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ...**  If  the  double-quoted  expansion  occurs
> within  a  word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the last
> parameter is joined with the last part of the original word.  When there are no positional parameters, "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e.,
> they are removed).

In `bash -c 'work "$@"' _ <the_line>`:

- command `bash` is executed with 4 arguments - `-c` `work "$@"` `_` and the line content
- bash sees `-c`

  - the next argument `work "$@"` is the script to execute
  - `"$@"` will expand to `"$1" "$2" ..`.
  - Actually, here there will be only 1 argument each time, so `"$@"` is going to be just equal to `"$1"` anyway.
- `_` is assigned to `$0`. TBH it's ignored. It's common to use `--` or `-` or `_` or just anything.
- `<the_line>` is assigned to `$1`

Comment: Just to answer your questions, I'm not authorize to copy keys across Server and liberty to run ansible which is internal to org policy.

Comment: I need to use `sshpass` at the moment as i don't have liberty and access to copy the keys.

Comment: `ansible` does the same as `sshpass`. The only thing the remote has to have any `python`, and you can run `ansible`.

Comment: @ KamilCuk - thanks for the info , i'm using ansible extensively in another env but for some reason we are forec to use this way.

Comment: @ KamilCuk, Could you please explain `'work "$@"' _` , as i'm still learning. if you could that will be really helpful.  i'm also using `cpu_info=$(sshpass -e ssh -q -t  $server sudo grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | awk 'NF==3{count++} END {printf count}')` which you suggested `nproc` thats really nice but we have RHEL5 systems still which do not have this thats why i need to use `proc` base info.

Comment: As I wrote above, I do not understand that `NF==3` - you already know it's the lines with `processor`. Just count them - `grep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: KamilCuk, Thank you .  you are absolutely right `grep -c` does the job but i was duing some stupid thing for `Printf`